# Looping through sql table and calculate figures in php

Tags: php, sql, database, database-table

I have a what seems a simple question but I cannot workout how to do it.

```
Employee id | dev_time | pm_time
1           |    4     |    5
2           |    2     |    3
3           |    6     |    2
2           |    3     |    6
3           |    4     |    4
1           |    1     |    5
```

I have a table on my localhost that looks like this. How do I find out the total time (dev_time + pm_time) spent by each employee? I require both the SQL statement and the while/for/foreach loops solution

> For example employee_id 1 has spent a total of 15hrs or employee_id 2 has spent a total of 14 hours

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Which rdbms are you using? (e.g. MySQL,MS SQL-Server,...)

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I have been using trying to use a foreach loop to loop through the table looking at each employee_id and trying to find the corresponding times.

Comment: @user2133387 You'll find that with SQL, it's much better to think of your queries in terms of _sets_ instead of trying to loop through your tables row by row. That's what you'll see in the answers below.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
  select employee_id, sum(dev_time + pm_time) as totalhours
    from mytable
group by employee_id
```

Sample output ([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65518/1)):

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | TOTALHOURS
1             15
2             14
3             16
```

Answer (score 3):

`I require both the SQL statement and the while/for/foreach loops solution`

Well I have some bad news for you. Instead of straight up code, I'm going to give you some links so you can figure this out yourself.

First off, you want to look into basic [SQL Operators](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqloperators.php). Then you'll see that the SQL statement you want to have the desired effect isn't all that difficult to deduce yourself.

Secondly, I'll give you the textual description:

`Query all tuples from the database`

`Loop through each one, first grabbing their dev_time value, and summing it with their pm_time value.`

`Store the sum value somewhere`

As mentioned by Conrad Friz, this textual description could lead to an "N+1 Selects Problem", and this can be done in a single statement, as you hopefully have worked out.

Hopefully you'll take this approach, rather than simply copying and pasting the code.

Comment: hmm, if you add a small requirement like *include only employees that have more > 2000 hours for 2012* the textual description of your solution could lead someone easily to a n + 1 selects problem.

Comment: Point made. Do you have a better suggestion? I would gladly edit it in :)

Comment: I wish I did. Textual models of sql statements are tricky. Perhaps just noting that it can be done in a single statement is enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this straight within the SQL, I'm not sure what DBMS you're using but in MySQL it's:

```
SELECT *, (dev_time+pm_time) AS total FROM table_name
```